# Core Bluetooth setNotifyValue isn't setting CBCharacteristics notifying property to true

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral

Hey guys I'm trying to get this bluetooth LE device to connect to the app and grab the values out. I'm using Core Bluetooth which is supposed to get the values out. I had it working but all the sudden it stopped notifying the values when it updates.

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
  peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
  print("peripheral did discover characteristics \(characteristic)")
}
```

}

In the delegate method call I'm setting every single CBCharacteristic object's notify value to true. This should mean that any value that it updates should call another delegate method

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)
```

However this method is not being called. In I added a print statement to print out each characteristics, but each single characteristics notify property is still set to NO when I set the value as true!

```
peripheral did discover characteristics <CBCharacteristic: 0x1700ac0c0, UUID = 28930002-C868-423A-9DC2-E9C2FCB4EBB5, properties = 0x12, value = (null), notifying = NO>
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check the properties of the characteristics to ensure that notify is supported?

Comment: I'm new to Core Bluetooth and I didn't think that was possible! I did that and interesting thing is that notify isn't supported unless I have this device's app and it's paired using that app. Now it can get notified. Thank you so much! I learned so much from you telling me this!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)` to see if a call to `setNotifyValue(_:for:)` was actually successful